# Powering RC Servos using Switching Power Supply

Tags: power-supply, servo

I have 3 RC HV Servos (working voltage 6-8.4V) ([link](http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__50468__Turnigy_8482_TGY_DS3509MG_High_Torque_BB_DS_MG_w_Alloy_Case_40kg_0_12sec_78g.html)). I purchased a 75 Watt Switching Power Supply ([link](http://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Mean-Well/HRP-75-75/?qs=hIaLxhCfWPB0I%252bFyiSQOfg%3D%3D)). The servos draw about 3amps at full load.Is a 75Watt supply sufficient or do I need more just to be safe? Also, is it safe to connect the servos directly to this supply or do I need to add a current limiting resistor between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a comment in your link, the maximum draw is 3A, so 3 could draw as much as 9A. That's 68W so your 75W supply appears to be adequate, at least to the extent the 3A represents a *peak* draw. To be 100% sure I'd like to see an official spec from the manufacturer that this represents stall current.

Chances are you'll not be running all three simultaneously at full load so I think you're probably okay. A supply like that (and it is from a reputable manufacturer- Meanwell) should gracefully current limit.

No you do not (should not) put a resistor in series, just connect them to the supply (observing polarity, of course, or you'll probably be ordering more of those nice servos).

By the way, you're apparently using a proper distributor (Mouser) so no worries, but I have seen counterfeit Meanwell supplies on the market so be careful with supplies outside official channels.

Comment: I've been trying to get the manufacturers spec sheet for several days now. I still haven't found it. So I have to rely on that comment in that page. Or I need to first test a single servo on the supply to see how much it draws.

Comment: Hopefully it will be non-destructive testing..